# Why I need add empty ccclippingnode between each slice part?

Tags: cocos2d-x, box2d

I split a ball into two part with ccclipingnode. but I found that I need create empty ccclipingnode or will cliping strange.

```
if(new1VecsCount>=3)addChild(Box2dItemSlice::createSliceBody(box->box2dBody->GetPosition(), box->box2dBody->GetAngle(), new1VecsSorted, new1VecsCount,pRot1));
addChild(CCClippingNode::create(CCNode::create()));
if(new2VecsCount>=3)addChild(Box2dItemSlice::createSliceBody(box->box2dBody->GetPosition(), box->box2dBody->GetAngle(), new2VecsSorted, new2VecsCount,pRot2));
addChild(CCClippingNode::create(CCNode::create()));
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution: http://blog.csdn.net/jusnxie/article/details/9277121

goto CCClippingNode::visit function, find "ccDrawSolidRect" line and modify :

```
glStencilFunc(GL_NEVER, mask_layer, mask_layer);  
glStencilOp(!m_bInverted ? GL_ZERO : GL_REPLACE, GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP);  winSize]), ccc4f(1, 1, 1, 1));  
ccDrawSolidRect(CCPointZero, ccpFromSize(CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize()), ccc4f(1, 1, 1, 1));
```

change to :

```
glStencilFunc(GL_NEVER, mask_layer, mask_layer);  
glClearStencil(!m_bInverted ? 0 : ~0);  
glStencilOp(!m_bInverted ? GL_ZERO : GL_REPLACE, GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP);  winSize]), ccc4f(1, 1, 1, 1));  
ccDrawSolidRect(CCPointZero, ccpFromSize(CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize()), ccc4f(1, 1, 1, 1));  
glClear(GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
```

You just need add "glClearStencil(!m_bInverted ? 0 : ~0);" and "glClear(GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);" to the right position.